# get package version when sub-packages are imported

Tags: python, python-import

I have a git repo which I turned into a package (according to these [instructions](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html))
It's file hierarchy is

- git_repo_name\folder1\functions1.py contaning func1a, func 1b
- git_repo_name\folder1_*init*_.py
- git_repo_name\folder2\functions2.py contaning func2a, func 2b, containing func2ca, func 1b
- git_repo_name\folder2_*init*_.py
- git_repo_name_*init*_.py    git_repo_name\setup.py
- git_repo_name\requirements.txt

I want to import like this

```
from git_repo_name.folder2 import func2a, func 2b
```

or

```
from git_repo_name.folder2.functions2 import func2a, func 2b
```

because that way I can always import rapo_name and check its version using

```
import repo_name
git_repo_name.__version__
```

but instead my import work like this:

```
from folder2.functions2 import func2a
```

and I can't get folder1 and folder2 to echo git_repo_name version from git_repo_name\setup.py
I tried adding  the following code
to *git_repo_name\folder1_*init*_.py* and to *git_repo_name\folder2_*init*_.py*

```
from pkg_resources import get_distribution, DistributionNotFound
import os.path
try:
    _dist = get_distribution('git_repo_name')
    dist_loc = os.path.normcase(_dist.location)
    here = os.path.normcase(__file__)
    if not here.startswith(os.path.join(dist_loc, 'git_repo_name')):
        raise DistributionNotFound
    except DistributionNotFound:
    __version__ = 'Please install this project with setup.py'
else:
    __version__ = _dist.version
```

but `git_repo_name.__version__` , `folder2.__version__` and `git_repo_name.folder2.__version__` all fail.

1. What needs to change in my file hierarchy to allow imports of the first form?
2. How can I get the 'folder' modules to know their version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The right file structure to allow this would be
git_repo_name\package_name\folder1
git_repo_name\package_name\folder2
git_repo_name_init_.py
git_repo_name\setup.py

and in my case package_name is git_repo_name.

This allows

```
import package_name
package_name.__version__
```